# MySQL triggers fires too many times

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I have a view in mysql which is made of three tables unioned together:

```
CREATE VIEW program_operator_jct_view AS
select
        program_id, 
        operator_code,
        'PROGRAM_OPERATOR' AS type
    from 
        program_operator_jct
UNION
    (select 
        program_id, 
        operator_code,
        'PROGRAM_GROUP' AS type
    from 
        program_operator_group_jct pg_jct,
        operator_group_jct og_jct
    where
        pg_jct.group_id = og_jct.group_id)
```

From this view, I create a summary table for increased performance, which is indexed so my results from this summary table can be returned via covering indexes:

```
CREATE TABLE `program_operator_jct_summary` (
  `program_id` int(7) NOT NULL,
  `operator_code` varchar(6) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`program_id`,`operator_code`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1


//BUILD SUMMARY PROCEDURE
delimiter //
CREATE PROCEDURE update_program_operator_jct_summary ()
BEGIN
DELETE FROM program_operator_jct_summary;
INSERT INTO program_operator_jct_summary select DISTINCT program_id, operator_code from program_operator_jct_view;
INSERT INTO trigger_record (name) VALUES ('update_program_operator_jct_summary');
END
//
```

I attached this procedure to the insert, update and delete triggers of the underlining tables which make up the summary table:

-program_operator_jct

-program_operator_group_jct

-operator_group_jct

EXAMPLE:

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_program_operator_jct_insert AFTER INSERT ON program_operator_jct
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
CALL update_program_operator_jct_summary ();
END
//
```

Here's my problem when I add (5) operators to the program_operator_jct:

```
INSERT INTO program_operator_jct (program_id, operator_code) VALUES 
('112', '000500'), 
('112', '000432'), 
('112', '000501'), 
('112', '000264'), 
('112', '000184')
```

This trigger runs (5) times, if I add 100 operators this trigger runs 100 times.  This is a nice place to use triggers because I don't have to worry about the summary table being out of date with the underlining tables.

However rebuilding a summary table for each value in an extended inserts is way too much of a performance hit (sometimes I add hundreds of operators to programs at a time).  I want the trigger to run once after the extended inserts are performed on the underlining tables.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trigger is doing its job, e.g. 'FOR EACH ROW'.

I don't believe that mysql gives you the option of running a trigger once at the end.

I'd call the stored procedure from your code after the INSERT has successfully completed.

If you're worried about forgetting, setup a cron job to run it every once in a while.

Good luck.

Comment: From the mysql 5.5 FAQ: `B.5.3: Does MySQL 5.5 have statement-level or row-level triggers? In MySQL 5.5, all triggers are FOR EACH ROW—that is, the trigger is activated for each row that is inserted, updated, or deleted. MySQL 5.5 does not support triggers using FOR EACH STATEMENT.`